# when should dataset reflect the updated rows count after an insert in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, dataset, insert-update

i have a sql database, and have created a dataset for a sample table in it.

The dataset is HotelDataSet2 and data table adapter to insert to it is Various_itemsTableAdapter.

```
 MsgBox(HotelDataSet2.various_items.Rows.Count)
 Various_itemsTableAdapter.Insert(Item_nameTextBox.Text, itemcode, PackingTextBox.Text, UomTextBox.Text, PriceTextBox.Text, RemarksTextBox.Text, TaxTextBox.Text, StatusCheckBox.Checked, Rate_inclusiveCheckBox.Checked)
 MsgBox(HotelDataSet2.various_items.Rows.Count)
```

This always reflects the same count, before and after inserting..But if i execute this

```
MsgBox(HotelDataSet2.various_items.Rows.Count)
Various_itemsTableAdapter.Insert(Item_nameTextBox.Text, itemcode, PackingTextBox.Text, UomTextBox.Text, PriceTextBox.Text, RemarksTextBox.Text, TaxTextBox.Text, StatusCheckBox.Checked, Rate_inclusiveCheckBox.Checked)
Various_itemsTableAdapter.Fill(HotelDataSet2.various_items)
MsgBox(HotelDataSet2.various_items.Rows.Count)
```

it shows the new count to be +1 of the old one. So i concluded that everytime i change some data to the table via table adapter, i have to always refill the dataset?? How is that useful then??

Comment: Answer updated, this should be more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going about this the wrong way. You should be using the `DataSet` to make your changes (ie, create `DataRow`'s with its tables and insert those rows into the table), then pass the appropriate `DataTable` from the `DataSet` to your `TableAdapter` in order to persist the changes to the database by calling the `Update` function on the `TableAdapter`

```
tableAdapter.Update(dataSetName);
```

Calling the `Insert` function directly only inserts that data into the table in the database itself; it does not have any effect on any local copies of the data (such as your `DataSet`).

*As a side note,* try to avoid using language-specific functions like `MsgBox`. Instead, to show a message box try calling `MessageBox.Show(...)`, as that is language-independent.

**Edit**

To clarify, the proper way to do this is to create a new `DataRow`, populate its columns with the new values, add that `DataRow` to the appropriate table, then pass the table to the `TableAdapter` through the `Update` function.

For example, I have...

```
A DataSet named myDataSet
A DataTable in myDataSet called MyTable
A TableAdapter for MyTable called myTableAdapter
Two columns in that table, FirstName and LastName
Two TextBoxes called txtFirstName and txtLastName
```

To insert a row with those values, I would do this:

```
DataRow row = myDataSet.MyTable.NewRow(); // creates a new row with the correct columns

row["FirstName"] = txtFirstName.Text;
row["LastName"] = txtLastName.Text;

myDataSet.MyTable.Rows.Add(row); // adds the new row to the in-memory table

myTableAdapter.Update(myDataSet); // persists all of the changes to the DataSet
```

Comment: you see, i have a set of textboxes and other form elemtns like listview, listbox, checkbox and combo whose values i will make the user enter and then insert to the database, can you tell me apart from tableadapter.insert what else do i have a choice?

Comment: thanks, now it makes more sense. When i perform the myTableAdapter.Update(myDataSet) it reflects in the database as well instantly right? I had more doubts and wanted to consult, can i reach you else where too, email or chat?

Comment: Yes, when you pass it to the Update command the changes are made to the database at that time. As for consultation, you'll likely get a better response by posting your questions here on Stack Overflow. There are many people on here smarter than I am who could help you faster than I could at any given time. If you wouldn't mind, though, marking this answer as "Accepted" if your issue has been resolved, I would appreciate it. Thanks!